# Any serious problems when making an old java web app run on new IE 8 browser?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, web-applications, software-estimation

I need make an quick estimation on project (not sure we got):
It's an old banking CMS java web app, but the UI aimed for getting near the winform style:

- Server: jdk5, weblogic 9 (JSP 1.x), only use weblogic internal servlet (not strut...).
- Client: winXP, Ie6.

It was design only for use with ie6 but now we need make it also run well on new client: ie8,ie7 on win7.
 I understand the most difference is the client: DOM and CSS. 
But my problem is we hasn't been worked with ie8, and I have not enough time to build an testing environment because our developing environment is not ready to make test (its remoting completely, and managed by another partner)

Any experience or suggestion to help me weighing this task need will be welcomed.

Edit: HTML, CSS is fairy outdated, not work on firefox at all, JS is barely procedure, no ajax, no plugins. 
Client PC is limited for banking and, internal use (user not be supposed to change config or choose the browser) 
Using activeX to manipulating printer and creating the report (increase ability to meet security problem )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Java, or weblogic. What you need to worry is javascript and css.

As long as your concern is limited to IE7 and IE8 only (ignoring Firefox, Chrome, etc), I think you are pretty safe. These two browsers have compatibility mode that should work with IE6 designed websites. Most problem would probably cosmetic rather than functions.

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, this is going to be impossible to tell without actually testing the application.

It'll totally depend on what kind of markup was used. Possible problems can range from near zero (if only standard markup, simple design, and basic Javascript or a framework like jQuery was used) to several weeks of fixing (heavy use of complex CSS rules optimized for IE6; heavy use of IE specific Javascript).

Comment: Thank you! I know it hard to specify without any certain practice but I just make a post to know if there any deadly obstacle make the estimation become far-gone wrong.

Comment: @pinichi you're welcome. The devilish thing is that there *can* be obstacles... Browser incompatibilities are always the hardest thing to calculate. What I would do is take a close look at one part of the app, maybe do a test run on IE8. You may be able to get some sort of impression from that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any DOM problems since IE8 hasn't had any significant DOM updates since 1998 while any other browser is far more advanced than that. CSS and, maybe, javascript will be the big issue since you say it doesn't work in any modern browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.)